# How to talk about overlapping partitions of a set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If I have a set $A$ and a number of sets $A_\sigma$ for each $\sigma \in \Sigma$ such that

$$A = \bigcup_{\sigma \in \Sigma}A_\sigma$$

Is there a concise and eloquent way of saying this in plain English? $A_\sigma$ are $\mathit{covering\ subsets}$ or $\mathit{overlapping\ partitions}$ of $A$ or something like this?

I will simply explain if I need to, but if there is already a term for this I would like to use it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If each $A_{\sigma}$ are disjoint, then they would be partitions. Otherwise, describing the sets as covers of $A$ is a good way to say this. You will hear the term "cover" come up when talking about open covers of compact sets, in the context of analysis.

Comment: Thanks. I would say that A is the least-upper-bound of all A_sigma but I already use this term to talk about a function similarly broken up in the same proof. To be clear, you are suggesting I say: "A_sigma is a collection of covering sets for A"?

Comment: What do you mean by "least upper bound?" The term "least" implies ordering. What sort of ordering do you have on these sets? 

In your example, $\Sigma$ is a set of indices and $X = \{ A_{\sigma} : \sigma \in \Sigma \}$ is your collection of covering sets.

Comment: Or (looking at the "set cover problem" on wikipedia) maybe I should say A_sigma is a covering set for A or that {A_sigma : sigma in Sigma} is a covering set for A?

Comment: I suppose I'm assuming the natural order for subsets. It was my impression that set-union was the specialization of the join operation for sets. so {1,2,3,4} is an upper bound for {1,2} and {1,3}, but {1,2,3} is the least upper bound.

Comment: Thanks ml0105, this definitely helped me re-word my explanation!

Comment: If $A_\sigma$ are disjoint and non-empty, then $\{A_\sigma\}_\sigma$ are partitions.  Merely "disjoint" without "non-empty" is not enough to get that conclusion.